# Why has an unsuccessful search time for a hash table a time complexity Θ(1+α)?

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I get the Θ(1) part is the time that uses to calculate hash table, but I don't understand the Θ(α) part.

In my view, the time complexity is Θ(n). Assume α is the expected length and the table has m slots. To ensure the key is not in the table, we need to search each slot, and each slot has α excepted length, so the total time is α times m, then it's Θ(n).

Could anyone tell me which part I didn't understand correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing if a given key is in the hash table doesn't need to test all slots. You simply calculate the hash value for the given key (1). This hash value identifies which slot the key has to be in, if it is in the hash table. So, you simply need to compare all entries (α) in that slot with the given key, yielding Θ(1+α). You don't need to look at the other slots because the key cannot be stored in any of the other slots.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand. So each given key is calculated in hash function, and get a certain number that direct to a certain location. In this way, it only needs to look at this slot. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's how a hash table works. The hash function maps the key to a single slot (which is what you call 'location'). Different keys can have the same hash value, i.e. they are mapped to the same slot (which is called a collision). Therefore you need to compare all keys in that slot with a given key (not it's hash value!) to find out if it is actually in there or not.